# How can I dismiss my slide menu while tapping outside?

Tags: swift

I have a hamburger menu which slides in from the site. It dismisses the menu every time I select a cell. I want to add a TapRecognizer so that it also dismisses it when you tap outside.

```
var isPresenting = true
let dimmingView = UIView()

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 1.0
}
```

Tapping outside should dismiss the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the parent view

after that on tap to use  `func location(in: UIView?) -> CGPoint` and to check if the touch is outside of the frame of the slide menu.

```
@IBAction func touchWasDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: view)
    if !slideView.frame.contains(touchPoint) {
        dissmiss()
    }
}
```

Connection gesture action to the method

[image]

Comment: Where does the IBAction come from?

Comment: I create the method through drag and drop from the storyboard instance of UITapGestrueRecognize  which is on the parent view.

Comment: Sorry I don´t get it.. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/8c3kSMAw) is my HomeViewController. Can´t I just use the **touchesBegan(_:with:)** method to dismiss the side menu when tapping outside?

Comment: I just edit my answer, and sorry I don't have time to check your code now.

Comment: How di I add the tapRecognizer to my parentView?  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchWasDetected(_:))) in the viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1):

Assign tap gesture delegate to your view controller. In the gesture method keep code to dismiss the menu. The delegate below allows gesture to receive touch only when touched outside the menu and is not close if it is from inside the menu.

```
@objc private func tapGesture(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        self.closeMenu()
    }

extension SharePathViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        let point = touch.location(in: view)
        return !menuView.frame.contains(point)
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried a few things by now but nothing really worked.. my menuViewController doesn´t do anything